# Multilingual store based on Sylius solution needed

Tags: symfony, sylius

I've been searching a solution for multilingual products store based on Sylius. As I've founded (if I'm right) the Sylius don't have native multilingual products functionality.

I'm designing virtual goods (photos) store in which I need multiple languages for each product.

Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

Currently im not using Sylius for same reason. There is Thelia2 e-commerce solution based on symfony2 core. But it does not use Twig (uses Smarty instead, i dont like that) and does not use Doctrine ORM. So as soon as Sylius will launch multilanguage support i will migrate 100% on Sylius.